# Javascript for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a button on a page

My manifest.json has content script inject.js
and inject.js is like this

```
var botao_comunidades = document.querySelector('a[href="#Communities"]');

var botao_teste = document.createElement('p');
botao_teste.innerHTML = '<a href="#">Test</a>';
botao_teste.className = "themeLightTransparency NSC";
botao_comunidades.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',p);
```

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Teste",
"version": "0.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Teste",
"icons": {
"16": "icons/icon16.png",
"48": "icons/icon48.png",
"128": "icons/icon128.png"
},
"default_locale": "en",
"permissions": [
"<all_urls>"
],
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
    "https://www.orkut.com.br/*"
  ],
  "js": [
    "src/inject/inject.js"
  ]
  ]
 }
]
}
```

and it does nothing
:(

Comment: @Teepeemm: You want to see the whole thing?  He's already showing what he believes to be the relevant portion.

Comment: With an extension, everything depends on the manifest.  If the javascript were truly the relevant portion, that'd be fine, but most of these questions end up relating to the manifest.  In this case, though: OP, I'm not the greatest at pure javascript, but it appears you don't insert `botao_teste` into the document.

Comment: still haven't found a solution.. T_T

Comment: If I run your javascript, the last line throws a `TypeError`, because `p` is undefined.  If I change the last `p` to `botao_teste`, then it works.  Is that the case with you as well?

Answer (score 1):

From your manifest, delete the extra `]` that closes content_scripts.js (if you want to make this exact code work, there are a few other steps mentioned at the end).  Then when I load your script, the console at the website says `Uncaught ReferenceError: p is not defined` on line 6.  Change the last line to `botao_comunidades.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',botao_teste);` and everything works.

Other steps to make *this exact code* work:

- Delete “icons” and “default_locale” from the manifest
- Change content_script.matches to “http://www.orkut.com.br/*”
- Change the first line of inject.js to use `querySelector('#signUpViewport’);`

---

Here's the finished product:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Teste",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Teste",
    "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
        "http://www.orkut.com.br/*"
        ],
        "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

src/inject/inject.js:

```
var botao_comunidades = document.querySelector('#signUpViewport');

var botao_teste = document.createElement('p');
botao_teste.innerHTML = '<a href="#">Test</a>';
botao_teste.className = "themeLightTransparency NSC";
botao_comunidades.insertAdjacentElement('afterend',botao_teste);
```

And a screen shot ("Test" is in the bottom left):

[image: Screen shot]

---

Now it's your turn to be a little more descriptive in how it's not working.